# Spring MVC: How do I store an application scoped key-value map (considering thread-safety)?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-mvc

My application handles an html form with a POST metod, and the webapp should generate a static file (xls) for the user entered data.

I'd like to generate a static link for user i.e. `/download/{uuid}`. This URI should return the static generated file so that user can share or bookmark this link (such link could be destroyed after some time, may be some days).

My webapp doesn't use any db, and I'd like to avoid using db only for one table with key-values data.

The question is how to implement this approach in Spring MVC considering thread safety?

Should I create a Spring bean with `singleton` scope with `syncronized` methods for adding/reading `Map` of uuid/file path?

Please, tell me the best way to solve this problem.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question per-se, but don't forget that an in memory map will go away when your app is restarted/crashes.  Consider structuring the token you return to the client such that it contains all the information you need to find the file again on the server. Then you don't have to worry about storing a mapping at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use an in-memory data structure, then a singleton scoped object would be one approach.  You could create a custom bean, or you could simply create a synchronized `HashMap` (by wrapping it using `Collections.synchronizedMap`), or a `ConcurrentHashMap` instance.

But the problem with that approach is twofold:

1. It doesn't scale.  If you have too many users, or the key-value data is to large, then you can end up using too much memory.
2. The key-value data will be lost when your server is (hard) restarted.

I think you should consider a database, or alternatively considering implementing persistent sessions and storing the key-value data as session state.

Comment: Eventually I came to conclusion, that using a database is simplest and fastest way to solve this task, and I guess in the future it will be easier to extend my app using db.

Comment: I would suggest a in-memory cache system like Redis or Memcached. We can store key value pairs there. No need of db and its quite fast

Comment: @Prashanth - Yes ... modulo that it doesn't scale beyond the size of (available) memory / virtual memory.  Also, you you have the cost of some kind of IPC to talk to the memcache daemon + the overheads of converting to / from Java objects in Java space.

Comment: @StephenC Certainly. I am just suggesting Redis/Memcached since they are widely being used by large scale applications http://redis.io/topics/whos-using-redis, http://techstacks.io/tech/redis

Comment: @Prashanth - Are they using Java too?  That is what this question is about: a large in-memory "map" for a Java application.

Comment: @StephenC Yes, some of them. But not sure whether they are using only for this. Since Redis/Memcached can also be used as a NoSQL datastore. What I am saying is, these systems can be used as a key-value store(map) outside of the application, when we have less space for Java application in memory or in that machine. Also the stored data will go away if the app is restarted/crashses as Adam B said.

Comment: But the flipside is that with memcached the data goes away if the daemon restarts ... unless you have a database as well.  And (of course) if you use a database with Java then a Java in-memory cache solves the persistence problem just as well.  (If you are going to make comparisons like that ... at least try to compare like with like.)

Comment: @StephenC Are you saying that in-memory cache does not have limits(in memory)?. If we compare daemon-restarts with application crashes then we will end up in believing nothing.  Ultimately Kerb was trying to handle one table with key-values data, so a cache service which is outside of the application which can also can store data in clusters would solve his problem when there are huge post requests hitting his Spring MVC application.

Comment: No.  I'm not saying that.  Both Java in-memory and memcached have limits ... determined by how much RAM you have.  And neither are persistent.  But a Java in-memory cache is simpler and probably faster than a memcached cache.

Comment: When the application wants to scale, the memory which we have should be used efficiently, which Redis does better. In practice, very large heaps do not perform well with Java(or any gc language).

Answer (score 0):

Thinking outside the box, there is one solution that requires no storage, and yet being thread safe. Instead of creating the file and then generate the static link (and put their relation in a map, database or other key-value storage), you create the resulting link *first*, and then you use the link to generate the name of the file using some kind of transformation method. Next, when the user requests the same file later on you use the *same* transformation method to re-generate the name of the file, and thus you need no storage at all! Simplest implementation of the transformation method is of course to use the url as the file name (be aware of URL encoding / decoding), but you can make is as difficult as you want.